# Except method gives me wrong answer just for one instance

Tags: c#, linq

I create a list by this command

```
var terminalList = sourceLists.Where(t => t.TagNo == tagList)
                              .Where(t => t.FromTerminal.Length > 0)
                              .Select(t => parseTerminal(t.FromTerminal))
                              .OrderBy(t => t).ToList();
```

It works fine for every `Tagno` except for one which create a list like this

```
terminalList={33,35}
```

When I use this command

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(terminalList.Min(), terminalList.Max())
                       .Except(terminalList)
                       .ToList();
```

I checked it. `terminalList.Min()` would be 33 and `terminalList.Max()` would be 35. and in this case `terminalList` has 2 items in it.

I get this answer:

```
result = {34,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67}
```

which is wrong the correct answer is `{34}`.

How can I trace the problem?

Answer (score 7):

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range(
    int start,
    int count
)
```

where

`start` - The value of the first integer in the sequence.
`count` - The number of sequential integers to generate.

so `Enumerable.Range(33,35)` generates you 35 elements starting from 33, an then you remove 33 and 35 and get the shown result

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(terminalList.Min(), terminalList.Max())
                       .Except(terminalList)
                       .ToList();
```

to this:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(terminalList.Min(), terminalList.Max() - terminalList.Min())
                       .Except(terminalList)
                       .ToList();
```

As Guru Stron said you are using `Enumerable.Range()` incorrectly.